# Problema con highchartr, insertUI y removeUI en Shiny R. Error en shinyapp.js

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Hola todos estoy trabajando con una aplicación `shiny` con una `navbarPage` varios `tabsetPanel`. Me gustria que los `ui` de cada `tab` panel fueran temporales, con esto quiero decir que espero lograr que la aplicación solo cargue el `ui` en el que esta el usuario. Esto para evitar generar un código demaciado largo. Para esto genero `ui` desde archivos `R` individuales para cada `tabsetPanel`, los cargo a la aplicación según se necesiten con la función `source("ui_temp_idpanel.R")`. Remuevo el `ui` del `tab` anterior en el que estuvo el usuario con ayuda de la función `removeUI` e inserto el nuevo `ui` en el `tab` en el que esta actualmente el usuario con la funcion `insertUI`. El problema fue cuando use la librería `highchater` para incluir un mapa *(es importante mencionar que cuanto se incluyen gráficas generadas con librería este problema no se presenta.)*. Cuando sólo hay un mapa no hay ningún problema, sin embargo cuando hay más de uno (en distintos `tabPanel`) aparece el problema. También me di cuenta que el problema se presenta debido al uso de las funciones `removeUI` e `insertUI`, ya que probé el caso en el que los `ui` de los mapas son fijos y el problema no se da. Alguna de las cosas que intente fue borrar el `ouput$id_mapa` del `tab` anterior cuando el usuario cambia de `tab`, creo que lo logre con `ouput$id_mapa<-renderHighChart({})`, pero no soluciono el problema.

Al inspeccionar la aplicación en un explorador este es el código de error que me arroja:

```
  GET http://127.0.0.1:5642/undefined 404 (Not Found)    
  VM114:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
```

Se podría pensar que hay un error al enviar el mapa a la función `hchart()`. Lo extraño es que al principio la aplicación funciona sin problema, es hasta que después de haber generado un mapa en el `tab1`, se genera un mapa en el `tab2` y entonces regresas al `tab1` cuando pasa el error. Después del error la aplicación deja de generar los mapas y depende del lugar donde corras `removeUI` e `insertUI` que la app puede presentar otros errores. Si se insiste en cambiar de tabs depues del error aparecen esto nuevos errores:

```
shinyapp.js:360 Uncaught Duplicate binding for ID mapa2
shinyapp.js:360 Uncaught Duplicate binding for ID mapa1
```

Esto es todo lo que se sobre el problema. He recreado el error en una aplicación más simple que les dejo continuación:

#### App de ejemplo que presenta el error.

```
#Ejemplo Mapa
nac<-list(type="FeatureCollection",
          features=list(list(type="Feature",
          properties=list(state_code=list(0),state_name=list("Nacional")),
          geometry=list(type="Polygon",
                        coordinates=list(list(list(-95,26),
                                              list(-91,26),
                                              list(-91,22),
                                              list(-95,22),
                                              list(-95,26)))))))
#Variable para insertar ui al inico de la app
inicio<-1


library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

#Crear uis para cambiar decuardo al tab
ui_mapa1<-tagList(div(
  highchartOutput("mapa1")
))

ui_mapa2<-tagList(div(
  highchartOutput("mapa2")
))


#ui
ui <- fluidPage(
   
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Problema con highchartr and removeUI"),
   
   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        colourInput("colormap",h3("Color"),value = "#2c3e50"),
        actionButton("mapa","Mapear",icon('globe'))
      ),
      
      # Main ppanel
      mainPanel(
        #En el tabsetpanel se comentaron los tabpanel con los ui fijos
        #y se incluyeron dos tabpanel para insertar ahi los tab donde ve el 
        #usuario.
         tabsetPanel(id="tabpanel",
           # tabPanel("Mapa1",div(highchartOutput("mapa1"),id="Mapa1")),
           # tabPanel("Mapa2",div(highchartOutput("mapa2"),id="Mapa2"))
           tabPanel("Mapa1",div(id="Mapa1")),
           tabPanel("Mapa2",div(id="Mapa2"))
         )
      )
   )
)

# server
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  #Se carga el ui en el tab2 al inicio
  if(inicio==1){
    insertUI(selector = "#Mapa2",
             ui=ui_mapa2)
    inicio<-2
  }
  
  
  #Se crean valores reactivos para guardar los tags, unos datos para el mapay
  #y dos valores para controlar la reactividad de los mapas
  rv<-reactiveValues(
    ulttag=NULL,
    acttag="Mapa2",
    data_mapa=data.frame(),
    mapa1=0,
    mapa2=0
  )
  
  
  #Cuando se cambie de tab corre este codigo
   observeEvent(input$tabpanel,{
     #Guarda en que tag estuvo anteriormente, y en cual esta actaulmente
     rv$ulttag<-rv$acttag; rv$acttag<-input$tabpanel
     
     #Encuentra el ui que debe insertar
     if(rv$acttag=="Mapa1"){
       uires<-ui_mapa1
     }else{
       uires<-ui_mapa2
     }
     
     #Remueve el ui del ultimo tag y inserta el ui del tag actual
     removeUI(selector = paste("#",rv$ulttag," > *",sep=""))
     insertUI(selector = paste("#",rv$acttag,sep=""),
              ui=uires)
   })
   
   
   #Cuando demos clic en el boton mapear carga los datos de cada tab
   #y cambia el valore reactivo
   observeEvent(input$mapa,{
     
     if(rv$acttag=="Mapa1"){
       data<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(0),c(4)))
       names(data)<-c("id.edo","value")
       rv$mapa1<-rv$mapa1+1
       rv$data_mapa<-data }else{#Mapa 2
         data<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(0),c(8)))
         names(data)<-c("id.edo","value")
         rv$data_mapa<-data
         rv$mapa2<-rv$mapa2+1
       }
      
   })
   
   
   
   ##Genara el mapa 1
   
   output$mapa1<-renderHighchart({
     rv$mapa1
     
     isolate(highchart(type = "map") %>%
               hc_chart(backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF") %>%
               hc_add_series(mapData = nac, showInLegend = FALSE, nullColor = "#424242",
                             borderWidth = 0,data = rv$data_mapa, value = "value",
                             joinBy = c("state_code", "id.edo"), name = "IVP" ,
                             dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.properties.state_name}'),
                             borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
                             tooltip = list(pointFormat='{point.properties.state_name}: {point.value}<br/>',
                                            valueDecimals = 2),
                             states=list(
                               hover=list(
                                 color= "#a4edba"
                               )
                             ))%>%
               hc_colorAxis(tickPixelInterval= 100,
                            minColor= '#E6E7E8',
                            maxColor=input$colormap)%>%
               hc_title(text ="Indice de Valoracón Predial")%>%
               hc_mapNavigation(enabled= T,
                                buttonOptions=list(verticalAlign= 'bottom')
               ) %>%
               hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
                          text = "Fuente: Elaboración propia",
                          href = "") %>% 
               hc_exporting(
                 enabled = TRUE
               ))
     
   })
   
   
   
   ##Genera el mapa2
   output$mapa2<-renderHighchart({
     rv$mapa2
     
     isolate(highchart(type = "map") %>%
               hc_chart(backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF") %>%
               hc_add_series(mapData = nac, showInLegend = FALSE, nullColor = "#424242",
                             borderWidth = 0,data = rv$data_mapa, value = "value",
                             joinBy = c("state_code", "id.edo"), name = "IVP" ,
                             dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.properties.state_name}'),
                             borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
                             tooltip = list(pointFormat='{point.properties.state_name}: {point.value}<br/>',
                                            valueDecimals = 2),
                             states=list(
                               hover=list(
                                 color= "#a4edba"
                               )
                             ))%>%
               hc_colorAxis(tickPixelInterval= 100,
                            minColor= '#E6E7E8',
                            maxColor=input$colormap)%>%
               hc_title(text ="Indice de Valoracón Predial")%>%
               hc_mapNavigation(enabled= T,
                                buttonOptions=list(verticalAlign= 'bottom')
               ) %>%
               hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
                          text = "Fuente: Elaboración propia",
                          href = "") %>% 
               hc_exporting(
                 enabled = TRUE
               ))
     
   })
  
  
 
}

# Correr aplicación
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer es un tema relacionado al uso del `tabPanel`. Te envío tu ejemplo corregido.

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(colourpicker)
#Crear uis para cambiar decuardo al tab
ui_mapa1<-tagList(div(
  highchartOutput("mapa1")
))

ui_mapa2<-tagList(div(
  highchartOutput("mapa2")
))


#ui
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Problema con highchartr and removeUI"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      colourInput("colormap",h3("Color"),value = "#2c3e50"),
      actionButton("mapa","Mapear",icon('globe'))
    ),

    # Main ppanel
    mainPanel(
      #En el tabsetpanel se comentaron los tabpanel con los ui fijos
      #y se incluyeron dos tabpanel para insertar ahi los tab donde ve el 
      #usuario.
      tabsetPanel(id="tabpanel",
                  # tabPanel("Mapa1",div(highchartOutput("mapa1"),id="Mapa1")),
                  # tabPanel("Mapa2",div(highchartOutput("mapa2"),id="Mapa2"))
                  tabPanel("Mapa1",highchartOutput("mapa1")),
                  tabPanel("Mapa2",highchartOutput("mapa2"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# server
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  #Se carga el ui en el tab2 al inicio
  if(inicio==1){
    insertUI(selector = "#Mapa2",
             ui=ui_mapa2)
    inicio<-2
  }


  #Se crean valores reactivos para guardar los tags, unos datos para el mapay
  #y dos valores para controlar la reactividad de los mapas
  rv<-reactiveValues(
    ulttag=NULL,
    acttag="Mapa2",
    data_mapa=data.frame(),
    mapa1=0,
    mapa2=0
  )


  #Cuando se cambie de tab corre este codigo
  observeEvent(input$tabpanel,{
    #Guarda en que tag estuvo anteriormente, y en cual esta actaulmente
    rv$ulttag<-rv$acttag; rv$acttag<-input$tabpanel

    #Encuentra el ui que debe insertar
    if(rv$acttag=="Mapa1"){
      uires<-ui_mapa1
    }else{
      uires<-ui_mapa2
    }

    #Remueve el ui del ultimo tag y inserta el ui del tag actual
    removeUI(selector = paste("#",rv$ulttag," > *",sep=""))
    insertUI(selector = paste("#",rv$acttag,sep=""),
             ui=uires)
  })


  #Cuando demos clic en el boton mapear carga los datos de cada tab
  #y cambia el valore reactivo
  observeEvent(input$mapa,{

    if(rv$acttag=="Mapa1"){
      data<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(0),c(4)))
      names(data)<-c("id.edo","value")
      rv$mapa1<-rv$mapa1+1
      rv$data_mapa<-data }else{#Mapa 2
        data<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(0),c(8)))
        names(data)<-c("id.edo","value")
        rv$data_mapa<-data
        rv$mapa2<-rv$mapa2+1
      }

  })



  ##Genara el mapa 1

  output$mapa1<-renderHighchart({
    rv$mapa1

    isolate(highchart(type = "map") %>%
              hc_chart(backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF") %>%
              hc_add_series(mapData = nac, showInLegend = FALSE, nullColor = "#424242",
                            borderWidth = 0,data = rv$data_mapa, value = "value",
                            joinBy = c("state_code", "id.edo"), name = "IVP" ,
                            dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.properties.state_name}'),
                            borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
                            tooltip = list(pointFormat='{point.properties.state_name}: {point.value}<br/>',
                                           valueDecimals = 2),
                            states=list(
                              hover=list(
                                color= "#a4edba"
                              )
                            ))%>%
              hc_colorAxis(tickPixelInterval= 100,
                           minColor= '#E6E7E8',
                           maxColor=input$colormap)%>%
              hc_title(text ="Indice de Valoracón Predial")%>%
              hc_mapNavigation(enabled= T,
                               buttonOptions=list(verticalAlign= 'bottom')
              ) %>%
              hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
                         text = "Fuente: Elaboración propia",
                         href = "") %>% 
              hc_exporting(
                enabled = TRUE
              ))

  })



  ##Genera el mapa2
  output$mapa2<-renderHighchart({
    rv$mapa2

    isolate(highchart(type = "map") %>%
              hc_chart(backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF") %>%
              hc_add_series(mapData = nac, showInLegend = FALSE, nullColor = "#424242",
                            borderWidth = 0,data = rv$data_mapa, value = "value",
                            joinBy = c("state_code", "id.edo"), name = "IVP" ,
                            dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.properties.state_name}'),
                            borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
                            tooltip = list(pointFormat='{point.properties.state_name}: {point.value}<br/>',
                                           valueDecimals = 2),
                            states=list(
                              hover=list(
                                color= "#a4edba"
                              )
                            ))%>%
              hc_colorAxis(tickPixelInterval= 100,
                           minColor= '#E6E7E8',
                           maxColor=input$colormap)%>%
              hc_title(text ="Indice de Valoracón Predial")%>%
              hc_mapNavigation(enabled= T,
                               buttonOptions=list(verticalAlign= 'bottom')
              ) %>%
              hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
                         text = "Fuente: Elaboración propia",
                         href = "") %>% 
              hc_exporting(
                enabled = TRUE
              ))

  })



}

# Correr aplicación
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Me avisas si me equivoqué en resolver este problema.

## ACTUALIZACION

De acuerdo a vuestros requerimientos...

```
#ui
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Problema con highchartr and removeUI"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      colourInput("colormap",h3("Color"),value = "#2c3e50"),
      actionButton("mapa","Mapear",icon('globe'))
    ),

    # Main ppanel
    mainPanel(
      #En el tabsetpanel se comentaron los tabpanel con los ui fijos
      #y se incluyeron dos tabpanel para insertar ahi los tab donde ve el 
      #usuario.
      tabsetPanel(id="tabpanel",
                  # tabPanel("Mapa1",div(highchartOutput("mapa1"),id="Mapa1")),
                  # tabPanel("Mapa2",div(highchartOutput("mapa2"),id="Mapa2"))
                  tabPanel("Mapa1",div(id="Mapa1")),
                  tabPanel("Mapa2",div(id="Mapa2")),
                  selected="Mapa2"
      )
    )
  )
)

# server
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  library(shiny)
  library(highcharter)
  library(colourpicker)

  nac<-list(type="FeatureCollection",
            features=list(list(type="Feature",
                               properties=list(state_code=list(0),state_name=list("Nacional")),
                               geometry=list(type="Polygon",
                                             coordinates=list(list(list(-95,26),
                                                                   list(-91,26),
                                                                   list(-91,22),
                                                                   list(-95,22),
                                                                   list(-95,26)))))))

  ui_mapa1<-reactive({tagList(div(

        renderHighchart({
        print(paste("1",rv$mapa1))

        highchart(type = "map") %>%
          hc_chart(backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF") %>%
          hc_add_series(mapData = nac, showInLegend = FALSE, nullColor = "#424242",
                        borderWidth = 0,data = rv$data_mapa, value = "value",
                        joinBy = c("state_code", "id.edo"), name = "IVP" ,
                        dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.properties.state_name}'),
                        borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
                        tooltip = list(pointFormat='{point.properties.state_name}: {point.value}<br/>',
                                       valueDecimals = 2),
                        states=list(
                          hover=list(
                            color= "#a4edba"
                          )
                        ))%>%
          hc_colorAxis(tickPixelInterval= 100,
                       minColor= '#E6E7E8',
                       maxColor=isolate(input$colormap))%>%
          hc_title(text ="Indice de Valoracón Predial")%>%
          hc_mapNavigation(enabled= T,
                           buttonOptions=list(verticalAlign= 'bottom')
          ) %>%
          hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
                     text = "Fuente: Elaboración propia",
                     href = "") %>% 
          hc_exporting(
            enabled = TRUE
          )

      })      

  ))})

  ui_mapa2<-reactive({tagList(div(

      ##Genera el mapa2
      renderHighchart({
        print(paste("2",rv$mapa2))

        highchart(type = "map") %>%
          hc_chart(backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF") %>%
          hc_add_series(mapData = nac, 
                        showInLegend = FALSE, 
                        nullColor = "#424242",
                        borderWidth = 0,
                        data = rv$data_mapa,
                        value = "value",
                        joinBy = c("state_code", "id.edo"), 
                        name = "IVP" ,
                        dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.properties.state_name}'),
                        borderColor = "#FAFAFA", 
                        borderWidth = 0.1,
                        tooltip = list(pointFormat='{point.properties.state_name}: {point.value}<br/>',
                                       valueDecimals = 2),
                        states=list(
                          hover=list(
                            color= "#a4edba"
                          )
                        ))%>%
          hc_colorAxis(tickPixelInterval= 100,
                       minColor= '#E6E7E8',
                       maxColor=isolate(input$colormap))%>%
          hc_title(text ="Indice de ValoracIón Predial")%>%
          hc_mapNavigation(enabled= T,
                           buttonOptions=list(verticalAlign= 'bottom')
          ) %>%
          hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,
                     text = "Fuente: Elaboración propia",
                     href = "") %>% 
          hc_exporting(
            enabled = TRUE
          )

      })

  ))})

  #Se crean valores reactivos para guardar los tags, unos datos para el mapay
  #y dos valores para controlar la reactividad de los mapas
  rv<-reactiveValues(
    ulttag=NULL,
    acttag="Mapa2",
    data_mapa=data.frame(),
    mapa1=0,
    mapa2=0
  )

  #Cuando se cambie de tab corre este codigo
  observeEvent(input$tabpanel,{
    #Guarda en que tag estuvo anteriormente, y en cual esta actaulmente
    rv$ulttag<-rv$acttag; rv$acttag<-input$tabpanel

    #Encuentra el ui que debe insertar
    if(rv$acttag=="Mapa1"){
      uires<-ui_mapa1()
      print(rv$acttag)
    }else{
      uires<-ui_mapa2()
      print(rv$acttag)
    }

    #Remueve el ui del ultimo tag y inserta el ui del tag actual
    if(!(rv$acttag==rv$ulttag)){
    removeUI(selector = paste("#",rv$ulttag," div",sep=""))}

    insertUI(selector = paste("#",rv$acttag,sep=""),ui=uires)
    print("nac")
  })

  #Cuando demos clic en el boton mapear carga los datos de cada tab
  #y cambia el valore reactivo
  observeEvent(input$mapa,{

    if(rv$acttag=="Mapa1"){
      data<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(0),c(4)))
      names(data)<-c("id.edo","value")
      rv$mapa1<-rv$mapa1+1
      rv$data_mapa<-data }else{#Mapa 2
        data<-as.data.frame(cbind(c(0),c(8)))
        names(data)<-c("id.edo","value")
        rv$data_mapa<-data
        rv$mapa2<-rv$mapa2+1
      }
  })

}

# Correr aplicación
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu aportación. Sin embargo parece que no me explique bien.  Lo que has echo es dejar las salidas fijas en el ui principal. Justo como se presenta en los dos ui intercambiables que se crean al inicio de la app #Crear uis para cambiar decuardo al tab
`ui_mapa1<-tagList(div(
  highchartOutput("mapa1")
))

ui_mapa2<-tagList(div(
  highchartOutput("mapa2")
))` sin embargo el objetivo es que cuando el usuario cambie de tab el contenido del tab anterior desaparezca es por eso que se asignaba una `div()` con una `id` para manipularlo con `removeUI` e `insertUI`

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el código de acuerdo a sus requerimientos. No olvide en responder.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda la aplicación esta funcionando. Mañana intentare  incluirlo en mi aplicación.

Comment: Hola colega la actualización funciona. Tendrá alguna idea sobre como cambiar el tamaño del mapa probé con la función `hc_size()`, sin embargo no tiene efecto.

Comment: En tu comando **hc_chart** añadele la propiedad **height** Y **width**. Por ejemplo... hc_chart(backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF",height="1000",width="1000")